# How to upload photo and photo's description TOGETHER in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, mysql

Here is what I am doing:  Allowing the user to upload a photo and two description fields of the photo to MySQL using their iphone app.  I have already figured out how to configure the app so that the text from the two description fields are uploaded (using PostURL and an accompanying .php file on my web server).

Where I am running into problems is how to add a photo into the mix, and have the photo AND text fields transmit together into the database into their corresponding columns (image, name, message).

What should my header and implementation files look like?  And as an added bonus, what should my .php file look like?  Here is how they exist currently, and as an FYI, this only works to transmit text, not the photo.

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kPostURL @"http://www.example.com/upload.php"
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate,      UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{

IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView *messageText;
NSURLConnection *postConnection;

UIImageView * theimageView;
UIButton * choosePhoto;
UIButton * takePhoto;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * nameText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView * messageText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection * postConnection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * theimageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * choosePhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * takePhoto;


-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender;



-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name;
-(IBAction)post:(id)sender;



@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize nameText, messageText, postConnection, theimageView, choosePhoto,    takePhoto,postData;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name {


if (name != nil && message != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];



    [postString setString:[postString   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


}

}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{

[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text = nil;
nameText.text = nil;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test1" object:self];

}

-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhoto) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
theimageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(^.^)"Hi sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Hi you can use (get, post, web services like soap, rest services like json) request.

From my experience if you like to send an image you have to use base64binary this is a string representation of array of bytes because I've never been able to send one array of bytes, but if is string you can send this normal without base64binary.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question.  I am looking for specific code that will fix mine above.  Thanks for the response though, NTTake.

Comment: Ok @Mike I'dont now how to make the back-end in php for receive data  but if you have the back-end I can help you with the front-end for iOS. Good Luck.

Comment: I can figure out the PHP, but can you help me code the front end files?  For instance, would you mind showing me how my code should look in both the header and implementation files?

Comment: hi @Mike yes I can but I have to now how to send that like post, get, or web services like soap, this is in the server side.

Comment: Well, the front end uses POST once in the code, and the rest is handled by the .php script (www.example.com/upload.php).  I do not believe you need POST, GET, soap, or Json to write the front end.  It should only make one call to the server, using the postURL

Comment: I need to now how that way the server expects the data because is Diferente depending on the type. @Mike I'm working right now if you like I can do this sending the data with post but later because I have to work.

Comment: That would be very nice of you and very much appreciated.  Thanks so much NTTake!!!!  You are a life-saver.

Comment: Hi @Mike can you give me youre email to send the project I make the code to send but I do not implement the code to take the image from the camera take care if you use the camera becouse you have to rotate the image if you dont do this the image is not in the right position.

Comment: backupemailsmk@gmail.com      Thanks NTTake!!

Comment: did you ever get this fixed. Im half way through the same problem. I did however, notice that if I changed my imageview to an image instead, it seemed to work. Otherwise I was getting a null image view.image for some reason, i believe because it wasn't being refreshed. Now I'm stuck at trying to get the right iOS code to work. I think I have the right php code. Please contact me if you did get it working.